# Is this legal syntax in c++? and How do I use crtp trick?

Tags: c++, crtp

```
template<template<typename>class Derived>
class Base{
    public:
        void interface(){
             static_cast<Derived&>(*this).something();
        }
};

template<typename T>
class Derived:public Base<Derived> {
    ...
};
```

Derived needs one template parameter but I only use unnamed parameter for class Derived in Base.
Can I use this syntax?
What I fix?
How can I access Derived in Base?

---

can I add using dType = typename Derived::type in base? in gcc version 10.2, I got errors like this;

```
test.cpp: In instantiation of 'class Base<Derived<int> >':
test.cpp:22:7:   required from 'class Derived<int>'
test.cpp:30:24:   required from here
test.cpp:13:9: error: invalid use of incomplete type 'class Derived<int>'
   13 |   using dType = typename derived::Type;
      |         ^~~~~
test.cpp:22:7: note: declaration of 'class Derived<int>'
   22 | class Derived:public Base<Derived<T>>{
```

I just add using dType = Derived::Type in your code.

Comment: Does `Base` really need to be a "template template"?

Comment: No, I just want to know whether this is legal and useful

Answer (score 2):

You can just explicitly give the template parameter a name inside of `Derived`:

```cpp
template<typename Derived>
class Base{
    public:
        void interface(){
             typename Derived::type some_variable;
             static_cast<Derived&>(*this).something();
        }
};

template<typename T>
class Derived:public Base<Derived<T>> {
public
    using type = T;
    ...
};
```